# Safe way to migrate project from typescript 3 to typescript 4?

Tags: typescript

I have a large monorepo (with lerna, react,...) written 2-3 years ago with typescript 3.7 and I want to upgrade it to typescript 4.8.
Are there any tools to compare and detect if there're any breaking change may happen between typescript version? Or a guide to do the upgrade in safe/confident way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you could make a new branch in your source control repo (if you have one) and start the migration.

Then, an easy way to check if your codebase works in TypeScript 4.8 is simply to install that version, run `tsc` on your code.

Also, there's [a list of breaking changes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes) on the TypeScript repo. You could go through those.

I'm not aware of any tools that could do this for you. However, if your project doesn't have any really complicated types, then it shouldn't be that hard to do all this manually.